# About Leader Board in Javascript (Array) Help Me Please

Tags: javascript

I need help with a score table for my game.

**-1-**    I have 4 variables:

```
var Player1Score= 44;
var Player2Score= 12;
var Player3Score= 45;
var Player4Score= 26;
```

**--2--**     i make a Array:

```
var MyArray=[Player1Score,Player2Score,Player3Score,Player4Score];
```

**--3--**        sort the array:

```
MyArray.Sort();
```

**--4--**        Print:

----------HIGHSCORES----------

```
                45

                44

                26

                12
```

MY QUESTION IS: **HOW I CAN PRINT THE NAME OF THE PLAYERS IN ORDER¿?**

LIKE THIS:

----------HIGHSCORES----------

```
PLAYER 3              45

PLAYER 1              44

PLAYER 4              26

PLAYER 2              12
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE. GREETINGS

Answer (score 1):

Store you score data like this:

```
scores = [
    { name: "John", score: 123 },
    { name: "Joe", score: 234 }
]
```

If you don't have names, then use any other properties like the player index.

Then sort the data with a custom sort function:

```
scores.sort(compareScores);
```

And provide the custom sort function:

```
function compareScores(a, b)
{
    return a.score - b.score;
}
```

You may need to swap a and b in this function if you want a different order.

Print it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
{
    name = scores[i].name;
    score = scores[i].score;
    ... do something with name and score ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var score_map = {score1 : player1, score2 : player2, score3 : player3,
  score4 : player4};
var score_array = [score1,score2,score3,score4].sort();
for (var score in score_array) {
  your_output_function(score_map[score]+" - "+score);
}
```

Associate the scores with the player names and store the association as a javascript object. Get your hands on the scores and sort them and then iterate through the keys and use the object that had the score/player associations to print out the players and their scores.